# How to make PyCharm's Project Files window display class/method names

Tags: class, methods, project, pycharm

Today my company's IT department installed a bunch of system updates on my Windows computer, and in the process they blew away the PyCharm IDE's memory of my projects and everything related to them. (This is PyCharm CE v4.5.1.)

I've rebuilt the project I'm working on now, and (so far) a couple of its run configurations. However, PyCharm's Project Files window no longer displays the classes and methods defined in each file. I relied heavily on that feature for navigation, and I can't find a procedure for recovering it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I found that I can make the Project window display the classes and methods (and functions outside classes) like this:

1. Select the Project (not Project Files) option in the leftmost dropdown.
2. Select "Show Members" in the "tools" (gear icon) dropdown.

The "Show Members" name threw me off because I'm not accustomed to thinking of files having "members." It does the job, though.